# External HDD unable to be formatted in W10

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I have an old 1TB external HDD, used it fine for ages no issues. I flashed Batocera (retro game Linux distr and my first time touching anything Linux) to the drive using Balena Etcher. After doing this and wanting to boot from the drive, the drive became invisible to my W10 PC in file explorer, BIOS, and W10 disk management. The flashed drive should have had a bootable drive partition visible after flashing.

I was still able to view the drive in Balena Etcher, so flashed again, same issue.

I was able to view the drive in Minitool Partition Wizard, so did a full wipe of it using this and then formatted the disk using this software to NTFS. Assigned drive letter 'Z:'

Problem is, the Z partition is visible in Windows file explorer but inaccessible, just blanked out and Properties shows 0mb.

W10 Disk Manager can now see the disk and that its 930GB, however it does not show 'NTFS'  under File System column and gives an error message 'cannot format volume because the volume is offline, try assigning a drive letter or path to the volume first' when I try to format using Disk Manager.

In Minitool Partition Wizard, the drive is visible and showing as NTFS. I can format the drive in this software but it just leads to the same problem again, not being accessible by Windows whatsoever. The drive spins up completely fine and nothing to suggest any physical issue with it.

I want to get this drive to a state where I can flash Batocera to it and actually boot it.

**DiskManager screenshot**:
[image]

**Minitool Partition screenshot**:
[image]

Comment: Minor note: one does not "flash" a HDD, which does not have flash memory (nor *burn*, as in a CD/DVD, which uses laser heat). One writes (and please don't ask me why *write* is correct, when we use neither pen nor pencil). Such are the vagaries of English as she are spoke.

Comment: And there are a few more details you need to know in order as to not be surprised when this sort of thing happen (as they should, always) nor wasting the time an effort of composing a question about very basic stuff. 1. Windows can't read Linux partitions. 2. The resulting drive is intended to be boot from, NOT intended to be used as a regular mass storage device. Keep that in mind for the next time and do NOT expect it to be readable in Windows after writing the ISO and resulting Linux partitions. 3. Batocera Linux is designed to be run from an USB flash drive, not an HDD.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, a *partition* was created, but no *format* is shown for Z: in the Microsoft tool, *diskmgmt.msc*, **even though [Minitool Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/) shows NTFS formatting.** A likely reason for this is that that last step, applying NTFS formatting, was not *committed*. In the image below, note the *Apply* button that is used to commit after each operation.

[image: Minitool Partition Wizard Apply Button]

To fix that, start anew, with *diskmgmt.msc*, Minitool Partition Wizard, [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/), or other drive utility.

- **Carefully** select the drive.
- Remove all partitions, and click *Apply*.
- Create one (or more) partition, and click *Apply*.
- Format the new partition, e.g., NTFS, and click *Apply*.

Why the two-step process? This forces the user to reconsider their actions. It is *so* easy to format the *wrong* drive accidentally.